# DjangoCMS populate the data of the model in multiple custom plugin

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, django-cms

I am using DjangoCMS for my website development. I need to use the Phone number and email for the firm in multiple places in the website. So I thought of writing a custom plugin with below model

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class ContactDetails(CMSPlugin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="000000000")
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="Enter the Email")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Enter Address")
```

And the below cms_plugins.py

```
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import ContactDetails

@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ContactDetailsPluginFooter(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ContactDetails
    name = _("Contact Plugin Footer")
    render_template = "contact_details_footer.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ContactDetailsPluginFooter, self).render(context,instance, placeholder)
        return context

@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ContactDetailsPluginHeader(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ContactDetails
    name = _("Contact Plugin Header")
    render_template = "contact_details_header.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ContactDetailsPluginHeader, self).render(context,instance, placeholder)
        return context
```

I have the templates as below.

**contact_details_footer.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="f-h-content">
                <h3>Call Us Now !</h3>
                <h2>{{instance.phone_number}}</h2>
                <p><a href="#">24/7 Available</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="f-h-content">
                <h3>Send Us Message !</h3>
                <h2>{{instance.email_id}}</h2>
                <p><a href="#">24/7 Available</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="f-h-content">
                <h3>Visit Our Dubai Office !</h3>
                <h2>{{instance.address}} ‬‬‬</h2>
                <p><a href="#">View Map</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**contact_details_header.html**

```
<div class="header-contact">
                       
    <ul>

        <li><span>Phone :</span> {{instance.phone_number}}</li>
        <li><span>Email :</span> {{instance.email_id}} </li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Free Consultation</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But here, when I add the same every time, I have to add the phone and email id and address. What should I do to make it enter once and use it multiple plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you mention is intentional because each plugin is a unique model instance stored in the database.

We can create a unique plugin instance that links to a single instance of ContactDetails. To do that we have to create a foreign key relationship so a ContactDetails instance can link to many plugins.

We can also use Django admin inlines to enable creating and attaching ContactDetails to a plugin.

**models.py**

```py
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models


class ContactDetails(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="000000000")
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="Enter the Email")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Enter Address")


class ContactDetailsPluginModel(CMSPlugin):

    unique_to_plugin_field = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        'Contact', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unique_to_plugin_field
```

**cms_plugins.py**

```py
class ContactDetailsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ContactDetails


@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ContactDetailsPluginHeader(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ContactDetailsPluginModel
    name = _("Contact Plugin Header")
    render_template = "contact_details_header.html"
    cache = False
    inlines = [
        ContactDetails,
    ]

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ContactDetailsPluginHeader, self).render(context,instance, placeholder)
        return context
```

Your templates can now access using the relationship such as: instance.contact.email_id

**contact_details_header.html**

```html
<div class="header-contact">            
    <ul>
        <li><span>Phone :</span> {{instance.contact.phone_number}}</li>
        <li><span>Email :</span> {{instance.contact.email_id}} </li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Free Consultation</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```